# Trying to run an Azure Function App locally from Visual Studio 2017 gives a 'func.exe does not exist' error

Tags: c#, function, azure

I have created a new Azure Function app with an Http Trigger in Visual Studio 2017 (which I have just updated to v15.8.4).
Using the generated function, when I try to run it I just get a message box with the error

```
The debug executable "C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionTools\Releases\2.5.2\cli\func.exe" specified in the 'FunctionApp1' debug profile does not exist.

Sure enough there is no func.exe at that location, just a func.dll.

The file C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionTools\Releases\1.3.0\cli\func.exe does exist.
```

I have successfully run an Azure function locally before but I assume updating Visual Studio a few times has broken something.
How can I get this working?

Answer (score 17):

I Deleted **AzureFunctionsTools** and **azure-functions-core-tools** from `C:\Users\ {YourUser} \AppData\Local`. And ran the solution again it downloaded the same tools and then executed without errors.

Comment: I deleted the folder and then re-started Visual Studio. Then start debugging. This seems to be the way to go!

Answer (score 9):

I eventually got this to work by changing the settings in the Debug screen.

I changed Launch from Project to Executable

I set Executable to C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func.exe

I changed Application arguments to start

I changed Working Directory to Sourcedirectory\FunctionApp1\FunctionApp1\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0

I would still love to know where the Project settings were getting their values from though...

[image: Debug Settings]

Comment: This worked for me, thank you so much man!

Answer (score 3):

In my similar case after installing Visual studio 2019 16.11.2 in a new Win 10 S.

- I had already AzureFunctionsTools version 3.23.5 installed with func.exe inside  the **cli** folder (without_x64 suffix)
- But my newly installed VS 2019 was looking for func.exe in a similar path with only one difference that was (_x64 suffix after cli).

> ```
> C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.23.5\cli_x64
> ```

- After getting no result trying a other solutions mentioned here I finally renamed the existing **cli** folder to **cli_X64** and it worked

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get this working?

In your case, it seems that there is no [azure function tools v2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools) , please have a try to install it.

```
npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@core --unsafe-perm true
```

Please also try to update the [Azure functions and Web Jobs tools] to latest version

**tool->Extensions and updates**

[image]

And then try to run the azure function, if there is no corrosponding version it will download it automatically.

[image]

**Test Result**

[image]

**Update**

Check the function tools from the path

`C:\Users\{userName}\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding.

Comment: I have followed your instructions - installed the latest azure functions tools 2 and checked I have the latest version of Azure functions and web jobs.
Unfortunately I still get the same error.
What has been configured to try to run func.exe from a location where it does not exist?
What command should be run to run the azure function locally?

Comment: @PaulDolphin Make sure that [Azure function tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#other-requirements) are updated to the most [recent version](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/VS-AzureTools-ReleaseNotes.md). We could check the function tools in "C:\Users\toms\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases"

Comment: I have 2.5.2 installed - there are loads of files in that directory but no func.exe for some reason.

Comment: It is very odd that if there is no func.exe file. We could found the func.exe is in the  path C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.5.2\cli

Answer (score 2):

I am able to get this working just by targeting `.Net Standard 2.0`.

Just change to  netstandard2.0  in the project file.

Application Settings

[image]

Debug Settings

[image]

There is no need of providing a path to the `func.dll`.

Comment: I actually got mine to work by switching Debug -> Launch from Executable to Project. My Azure func was targeting .net framework 4.7.2 and my VS was 2019 Pro v16.5.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having on a fresh install of Visual Studio 2019 (had to uninstall 2017), and it was irritating me to no end.

I have found a solution to the problem, but no reason as to why this problem happened nor why Visual Studio deemed it necessary to make it so hard to fix things (they have no option of installing or reinstalling Azure Functions Tools in VS 2019 or even outside of it).

**Solution:**

Find a way to download the release. I used npm: `npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3`
(`-g` is global but you can install it locally, `@3` will install the latest 3.x.x)

Replace the entire contents of `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.4.1\cli_x64` with the version you installed.

For me, it was all the files in `\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is combination of above two answers .

Same error I also faced due to anti-virus but can't modify anti-virus since it can be changed by IT Security/networking team and process is time-taking & long process. Another workaround is :

1. Install `azure-functions-core-tools` via `npm`

   `npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@3`
2. Change **Executable** & **Working Directory** in **Debug** settings for azure Project settings

**Working Directory** : `C:\<Project path>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1`

**Executable** : `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func.exe`

[image]